# MySQL Aggregate function recordset to list in JSTL+Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jstl

There is a native SQL request

```
org.hibernate.Session HBsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

String SQLrequest = "SELECT prods.nom as nom, COUNT( res.productID ) as count FROM resultats AS res, products AS prods WHERE prods.productID = res.productID GROUP BY nom";

SQLQuery query = HBsession.createSQLQuery(SQLrequest);
List result = query.list();
```

it returns 4 objects

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1f208d0f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@6e7f349f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@cbad993
[Ljava.lang.Object;@17c5b9be
```

from code

```
<c:forEach items="${pageScope.result}" var="item">
${item}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

but a try to access the properties 'nom' or 'count' (according the SQL "prods.nom as nom, COUNT( res.productID ) as count" ) of this objects from code

```
<c:forEach items="${pageScope.result}" var="item">
${item.count}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

gives an exception

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "count"** 
or 
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nom"**

the try to declare the class which corresponds to results of this request and cast it also did not give any success. 
the question is - how to access the fields of the objects in this case? 
thank you in advance.

Comment: Your query returns a List<Object[]>. Each Object[] inside the list has two elements: nom and count. Why don't you use a JPQL query (that would return te same thing)?

Comment: does not matter. i even made a class
`public class Aggregation {
    
    private String nom;
    private Integer count;
}`
and cast List<Aggregation> result = query.list(); - no errors
but any try to access 

`<c:forEach items="${pageScope.result}" var="item">
${item.nom}<br/>
</c:forEach>`

gives 
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nom"**
exception

Comment: You didn't read my comment. Your query is returning a List<Object[]>. Casting it to a List<Aggregation> won't magically transform each array in the list into an Aggregation. An array is an array, and will stay an array. A cast does not transform arrays into something else. Accept the fact that your list contains arrays of two objects. Don't try to pretend it contains something else.

Comment: I get It. item[0] and item[1] work. thank you.